# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_react2.default.createContext((0, _getTheme2.default)())')

Tags: react-native

Im trying to run this React native app and after installing its dependencies (npm install) and running the app with react-native run-android I am getting this error:

[image: react-native-material-ui v1.19.0]
After googling this error I found this:  [Solution attempt](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/issues/442)

Which says that I should upgrade the material-ui library.
After updating to the version 1.30.1 of the library I get the same error.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^0.0.11",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.3",
    "react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.0-alpha.41",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.30.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.70",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "4.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.1.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./fuentes/"
    ]
  }
}
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I updated my React and React Native versions to the latest available.